# getting an error while trying to run my app with firestore: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm currently working on an app in which you can keep track of Root Canal patients and it was working fine for a long time...but after the new update of the `firebase` package in expo...I've been getting an error while trying to sign up. It says "Attempted to assign to readonly property" but my cloud firestore rules are set so that it is allowed. So, I am not too sure about what I did wrong.

This is the firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 12, 31);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code for the sign up function:

```
onSignUp = async (email, password) => {
    firebase // used import * as firebase from 'firebase/auth'
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.state.modalEmail,
        this.state.modalPassword
      )
      .then(() => {
        firestore // used import * as firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(this.state.modalEmail)
          .set({
            username: this.state.username,
            email_id: this.state.modalEmail,
            clinicName: this.state.clinicName,
            age: this.state.age,
            phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber,
            tablets: []
          });
        this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
        this.props.navigation.replace("Home");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert("Coudn't create user", error.message);
        console.log(error)
      });
  };
```

the error I'm getting:

[image]

If you have any idea on what I did wrong or what I could do to fix this issue please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt that this is related to your security rules. Does the error message tell you what property it is that you're illegally assign a value to?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no...I changed the `console.log(error)` to `console.warn(error)` to see if there were any stack traces but there was none.

Comment: "Attempted to assign to readonly property" Where/when does this error show up?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen after I press the sign up button...when I'm trying to add the user's information to the firestore database

Comment: Can you show (screenshot) the error? I have a feeling I may be missing something about the cause.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah...I've added it to my post

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see where that might be happening. Hopefully somebody else spots it.

Answer (score 2):

If your using firebase 9, the signature is changed.  the auth object needs to be passed as first parameter.

```
const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth